# Angular Directive not displaying a label

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm making a directive for a textfield in Angular. I have successfully gotten the textfield to show up and work. Based on whats inside inside the textfield I have a message displaying. For some reason the message wont show up.

Here is my initial code that I'm trying to convert into a directive:

```
<form name="objectiveForm">
  <p ng-if="requireObjectiveToBeSpecified"
     ng-class="{'has-error': (objectiveForm.objectiveInput.$touched || objectiveHasBeenPreviouslyEdited) && explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length < 15}">
     Add a goal: what does the exploration help people to do?
    <input name="objectiveInput" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="explorationObjectiveService.displayed"
         placeholder="Learn how to ...">
    <span class="help-block"
         ng-show="(objectiveForm.objectiveInput.$touched || objectiveHasBeenPreviouslyEdited) && explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length < 15" style="font-size: smaller; color: #a94442">Please provide a complete sentence that describes what this exploration is about.</span>
  </p>
</form>
```

This is the code I'm replacing it with:

```
<exploration-objective-editor ng-if="requireObjectiveToBeSpecified"
    label-text="Add a goal: what does the exploration help people to do?"
    form-style="{'font-weight': 'normal'}">
</exploration-objective-editor>
```

Here is my HTML code for the directive, file name = **exploration_objective_editor_directive.html**:

```
<form name="objectiveForm">
  <p ng-class="{'has-error': (objectiveForm.objectiveInput.$touched || objectiveHasBeenPreviouslyEdited) && explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length < 15}">
  <label for="explorationObjective" ng-style="<[::formStyle]>"><[::labelText]></label>
  <input id="explorationObjective" type="text"
         class="form-control protractor-test-exploration-objective-input"
         ng-model="explorationObjectiveService.displayed"
         enter code hereng-blur="onInputFieldBlur()" placeholder="Learn how to..." ng-trim="false">
  <span class="help-block" ng-show="(objectiveForm.objectiveInput.$touched || objectiveHasBeenPreviouslyEdited) && explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length < 15" style="font-size: smaller">
    <em>In a complete sentence, tell people what they'll learn from this exploration.</em>
    <span ng-if="explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length > 0">
      <em>Characters used: <[explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length]>/100</em>
    </span>
  </span>
</p>
```

Here is my JS code for the directive, file name = **ExplorationObjectiveEditorDirective.js**:

```
oppia.directive('explorationObjectiveEditor', [
    'UrlInterpolationService', function(UrlInterpolationService) {
      return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
          // The text for the label of the field.
          labelText: '@',
          // Additional CSS style to define the width and font-weight.
          formStyle: '@',
          // The method to call when the input field is blurred.
          onInputFieldBlur: '&'
        },
        templateUrl: UrlInterpolationService.getDirectiveTemplateUrl(
          '/pages/exploration_editor/' +
          'exploration_objective_editor_directive.html'),
        controller: [
          '$scope', 'explorationObjectiveService',
          function ($scope, explorationObjectiveService) {
            $scope.explorationObjectiveService = explorationObjectiveService;
          }
        ]
      }
    }
]);
```

### This is what I want it to look like:

[image: This is what I want it to look like]

### This is what it looks like right now:

[image: This is what it looks like right now]

Comment: Seems like you have issue in `ng-show` directive in `<span class="help-block" ng-show="(objectiveForm.objectiveInput.$touched || objectiveHasBeenPreviouslyEdited) && explorationObjectiveService.displayed.length < 15" style="font-size: smaller; color: #a94442">Please provide a complete sentence that describes what this exploration is about.</span>`. Please check it or create a plunker

Comment: Read [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).